# php echo inside html tag

Tags: php, html

Every time I run php amongst html, regardless of the order, the php is always run last. For example;
When I run this:

```
<h2>Admin: Events</h2>
<form action="php/admin_event.php" method="post">
Event Name:<input type="text" name="event"><br>
Start Date:<input type="date" name="startdate"><br>
Start Time:<input type="time" name="starttime"><br>
Finish Date:<input type="date" name="finishdate"><br>
Finish Time:<input type="time" name="finishtime"><br>
Venue:<input type="text" name="venue"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Event</th>
<th>Start Time</th>
<th>Start Date</th>
<th>Finish Time</th>
<th>Finish Date</th>
<th>venue</th>
</tr>

<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","littleathletics");
if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL.";
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from events");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td><?=$row['Event'];?></td>
<td><?=$row['StartTime'];?></td>
<td><?=$row['StartDate'];?></td>
<td><?=$row['FinishTime'];?></td>
<td><?=$row['FinishDate'];?></td>
<td><?=$row['Venue'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>

<hr>

<h2>Admin: Downloads</h2>
<form action="php/admin_downloadupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">...etc
```

I would prefer it if (for example) the hello came before the goodbye. Is there something wrong with my code? If not, is there a way to achieve the intended result?

I need some parts to be written in php because of sql data that I am presenting.

EDIT: the entire table is being displayed at the very end of the html document.

Comment: No it isn't. Check the source.

Comment: By `no it isn't` he means that your script actually outputs `Hello World` `Goodby World`, and he's right.

Comment: You should show us your actual code, not some fictional example. When descriptions as these come up, it's typically the placement of functions and their later execution which is confused.

Comment: You're right. I just tried the example and it worked as intended haha. I'll have to review my own html.

Comment: PHP scripts include HTML inside of them.  The PHP is not 'run' before or after the HTML, it's all interpreted from top to bottom.  Also, just FYI, HTML isn't a language, it's a markup - that is, it's just a way of presenting a string that the browser will recognize.  There's no logic (e.g. `if/else`) in HTML.

Comment: You might want to check also if the second element has some `float` css property. In that case, it'd appear first, even though in the code it's last.

Comment: I dont have any css in my php file unfortunately, but I don't know whats happening. I have included my real code, but there is more which I dont feel is necessary to include to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Which output appears to be generated out of order?

Comment: the table is appearing at the end of all the html; both the headers for the table and all of the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unclosed `<table>` element. It starts before the first PHP code, but is never closed. You probably want to close it here:

```
<td><?=$row['Venue'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
</table> <!-- Add this line -->
<hr>
```

You should also verify that short-open tags is enabled in your PHP configuration (it is disabled by default in recent versions), or change the shorthand version of the echo statements from:

```
<?=$row['Event'];?>
```

to:

```
<?php echo $row['Event']; ?>
```

This change will make your code more portable: it will work on servers with or without short-open tags enabled.

Comment: Ahaha silly me thank you very much =)

Comment: You're welcome! Enjoy.